# How to go from matrix to bra-ket representation of the CNOT?

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises

I have the following definition for CNOT gate form my notes:

> [image: Blockquote]

I am trying to derive the bracket notation form the matrix version, can someone help me to see where I am going wrong:

$$U ̂_{CNOT}        =|00⟩⟨00|+|01⟩⟨01|+|11⟩⟨10|+|10⟩⟨11|$$
$$=?=$$
$$=(|00⟩⟨00|+|01⟩⟨01|)  +(|1⟩⟨0|   ) $$
$$=(|0⟩⟨0||00⟩⟨00|+|0⟩⟨0||01⟩⟨01|+|0⟩⟨0||10⟩⟨10|+|0⟩⟨0||11⟩⟨11|)  +(|1⟩⟨1||0⟩⟨1|+|1⟩⟨1||1⟩⟨0|   ) $$
$$=|0⟩⟨0|⊗(|00⟩⟨00|+|01⟩⟨01|+|10⟩⟨10|+|11⟩⟨11|)  +|1⟩⟨1|⊗(|0⟩⟨1|+|1⟩⟨0|   ) $$
$$U_{CNOT}      =|0⟩⟨0|⊗I+|1⟩⟨1|⊗σ_x$$

The above would be make sense if:

$$|1⟩⟨1|⊗(|0⟩⟨1|+|1⟩⟨0|   )=(|1⟩⟨1||0⟩⟨1|+|1⟩⟨1||1⟩⟨0|   )=?=(|1⟩|0⟩⟨1|⟨1|+|1⟩|1⟩⟨0|⟨1|   ) $$

But why would this be correct but not:
$$|1⟩⟨1|⊗(|0⟩⟨1|+|1⟩⟨0|   )=(|1⟩⟨1||0⟩⟨1|+|1⟩⟨1||1⟩⟨0|   )=?=(|1⟩(0)⟨1|+|1⟩(1)⟨0|   )=|1⟩⟨0| $$

Comment: related https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5246/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8247/55

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt at an answer is a bit ropey in a few places. For starters, you need to be consistent about the number of qubits you have in places. This is a two-qubit operation, so your kets will always have a total of 2 qubits, and your bras will always have a total of two qubits. On your third line, one term only has 1 qubit in each. On your fourth line, you suddenly have 3 qubits in some terms.

I suspect what might help you is putting a subscript on your bras/kets to keep track of which one each term applies to. By that, I mean that you should write out something like $|01\rangle\langle 10|$ as either $|0\rangle_A|1\rangle_B\langle 1|_A\langle 0|_B$ or, just $|0\rangle\langle 1|_A\otimes |1\rangle\langle 0|_B$. These things are all equivalent.

So, for manipulating the description of cNOT, you start from
$$
|00\rangle\langle 00|+|01\rangle\langle 01|+|11\rangle\langle 10|+|10\rangle\langle 11|,
$$
which I'm instead going to write as
$$
|0\rangle\langle 0|_A\otimes |0\rangle\langle 0|_B+
|0\rangle\langle 0|_A\otimes |1\rangle\langle 1|_B+
|1\rangle\langle 1|_A\otimes |1\rangle\langle 0|_B+
|1\rangle\langle 1|_A\otimes |0\rangle\langle 1|_B
$$
Now we can group some terms
$$
|0\rangle\langle 0|_A\otimes (|0\rangle\langle 0|_B+|1\rangle\langle 1|_B)+
|1\rangle\langle 1|_A\otimes (|1\rangle\langle 0|_B+|0\rangle\langle 1|_B).
$$
Now you can recognise the two terms in brackets as $I$ and $X$ respectively.